# How to undo graphics driver install

Tags: drivers, apt, ati, fglrx

I have an AMD A8 5600K with the Radeon 7000 series graphics. Last night, I upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04 to 14.10. Graphics were not running properly after the upgrade, so I ran the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install fglrx-core

sudo apt-get install fglrx

sudo apt-get install gksu

sudo amdconfig --initial
```

Then, I rebooted the system, and it booted to a blank screen with the white mouse cursor. I had had to get the old Windows laptop out to ask for help.

Answer (score 0):

Start by removing the `flgrx` applications:

`sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx-core fglrx`

The load ppa-purge  `sudo apt-get install ppa-purge`  -  this program will attempt to remove applications installed from a ppa, and mark the ppa as being unused.

`sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates`

Remove and re-install the xorg drivers:

`sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf`

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64`

Finally, run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`